# Bash Shell echo/printf how to format output the right way

Tags: bash, shell, printf, echo

My current snippet of code looks like this ...

```
#Location of network config files
nfds="/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/"

#Standard prefer of network config files
fil="ifcfg-"

#Array variable that feeds "$nic"
cards= array loop built from "nic=$(ls /sys/class/net | grep en)"

#Set color for Divice labile
div="\033[38;5;39m"

#Set Fix format and colour info
fix="\033[38;5;118m"

#Set color for OK
ok="\033[38;5;28m"

#Clear All font and color info
ctf="\033[0m"

function currentCardDefRoute(){

    defr=$(grep DEFROUTE $nfds$fil$cards | cut -d = -f 2) 

    if [[ $defr = "yes" ]] || [[ $defr = "no" ]]; then
        echo -e " "$div$cards$ctf"'s current default route is\t"$div$defr$ctf"\t\t\t\t   ["$ok"OK"$ctf"]"
        $st
    else
        echo -e " "$div$cards$ctf"'s current default route is \t"$fix"Missing"$ctf"\t\t\t   ["$fix"PLEASE FIX"$ctf"]"
        $st
    fi

}
```

I indent 1 space on all echo lines for readability and consistent formatting. Keeping output readable and easy to understand.

Im looking to us the "columns" option and make the output more dynamic and have the format consistent no matter the screen size or var result. I would love to also get rid of all the "\t"s in my code. I have tried printf to no success.

I googled a lot of different ways and not seen the specific answer Im looking for or a variation I can draw an answer from.

Thank you for your help.
btw. This is the first code I have ever written so go easy guys :)

Comment: please edit your Q with actual data/sizes/etc that put a scope to "make the output more dynamic and have the format consistent no matter the screen size or var result". For instance, if you have an 80 col screen, but 120 wide data, what do you want to happen? **But** basically, `printf` should be where you're spending your time on research. Once you understand 20-30% of the `man printf` doucmentation (by doing small samples), the rest will be obvious. Some `printf` man pages even have a section labeled `examples`. Good luck.

Comment: As you have a `c` tag, I'll mention that the `printf` in the `c` language is the "parent" of the shell `printf` functions. I'm not sure if you think you need to code in `c` to use `printf`, but you don't. (This one looks pretty good, but the features may differ depending on shell and OS versions : http://ss64.com/bash/printf.html ) .  Good luck.

Comment: This is neither related to C nor to `printf` as defined by the tag (which is related to the C functions C).

Comment: The output is never more then 80 col I made sure of that in the rest of my code. I have researched printf and watched a lot of videos on youtube Kris Occhipinti and various others. Columns seams to be the syntax I need the help on, I will read more pages on what you suggested and see what I can find. Thank you

Comment: In the selection of keywords I wasn't left with to many options I though worked. `C` was suggested but the site, I understand its not. But `printf` I believe is.

Comment: Side note: you can use variable references like `$var` inside double-quoted strings.  You don't have to open and close the strings around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try using the [column](http://linux.die.net/man/1/column) utility.  It's sole purpose is for formatting output into columns.  That may be easier than trying to do the same thing with `echo` or `printf`.

If you have to use `printf`, you'll want to use a format specifier like `"%25.25s"`.  The first number is the "minimum field width", which (in this case) causes the output to be at least 25 characters wide.  If the output is shorter, it's padded with whitespace.  The second number indicates the maximum number of characters to print.  When these two numbers are the same, it effectively says to print the string in a field that's exactly 25 characters wide.  You can use this to force varying-length strings to take up the same amount of space on the screen.